# Is Windows Workflow Foundation appropriate for a CPU-heavy async application?

Tags: workflows, wcf, async, asynchronous-programming, workflow-foundation

At one of the DevDays conferences a presenter said that Workflow Foundation isn't just for applications that require persistence, but they can make it easier to write and maintain Async WCF code and the corresponding error handling.  (try.. catch)

- Assuming that is true, is Workflow Foundation able to use all the CPUs in a system? (Async IO)
- What WF-specific guidance is needed before writing a CPU-heavy Async WCF application within the WF framework?  (only tips that are specific to Workflow Foundation)

Comment: If WF can handle `async`, then by definition it can light up all the cores.  Your second bullet is too broad.

Comment: @RobertHarvey  It was, I clarified .

Comment: Yeah, that's fair enough.